# Chrome extension - getting Content-Type in onBeforeRequest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In a chrome extension I need to know what is the Content-Type of the request in `onBeforeRequest` callback, because if the Content-Type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` I want to decode the data in `requestBody`. however according to the life cycle documentation (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) the http headers are not yet available during `onBeforeRequest`, so I don't know what is the Content-Type. is there a way to know if the data is url-encoded during `onBeforeRequest`?

Comment: I was referring to headers in the request, not in the response... in any case I understand that I must listen to onSendHeaders as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at the time you desire. [`webRequest.onBeforeRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest) fires prior to the request being made. The data you want is something that is provided by the server in response to the request. You are looking for header information. The earliest this is available is in the [`webRequest.onHeadersReceived`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onHeadersReceived) event.